# Keep the javascript fully separated from markup on primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, dom-events

I'm working on a web interface with the help of primefaces framework.

In that interface, one of the objectives is to have the code divided in javascript functions that do not share information between each other and they don't allow being invoked by other parts (that eases testing and reduces the number and complexity of possible use-cases).
All "parts" are encapsulated using:

```
(function (window, document, undefined){
    var $ = window.jQuery;

    // main content here

})(window,document);
```

The communication required between each part is minimal and the required one is made using DOM events where an object is passed between each other. (if the event is not caught, it's just a functionality that didn't act. If it caused something to break, the js does not stop working, among other reasons).

This has been working for quite a while with minimal bugs found until I had to work with jsf+primefaces.
By reading the documentation, primefaces has many XML tags that do not map to HTML tags. One of the main ones I have to work with is `<p:ajax>`.

This tag was many on*-like attributes whose concept works much like the HTML3's ideology of writing javascript in HTML's "on*" attributes. Still, those `<p:ajax>` are always attached to specific XML elements like `<h:inputText>` or `<p:commandButton>` and that's where I started looking at.

In primefaces documentation, there's information about the inline on* attributes but I was fully unable to find information about jsf or primefaces' personalized DOM events.

How it appears with primefaces, I'm forced to change the javascript code so that functions/methods can be called inline in the HTML. That would require a lot of work also because, depending on the situation, the js code might even not be there (because the feature it enables is not required for that page).

How do I make the system on primefaces such that I have my javascript fully detached from the jsf/primefaces XML (and the whole HTML output I can manage).

EDIT:
I ran out of ideas on where to look at, I'll work on looking at primefaces source code now. I may get better luck there.

EDIT:
Meanwhile I got some ideas for searching using different keywords and I found this(see: "Client Side API"):
http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/primefaces/users-guide/p-ajaxStatus.pdf

This is near what I wanted but it seems like it does not exist for the elements I mentioned above. I'll work on continuing searching for more.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, investigation, etc... I was finally able to understand the whole story of what was happening.

Primefaces was doing everything right after all! The `<p:ajax>` has the correct code to send all the events it should! The problem lies in jQuery itself.

jQuery's `trigger()` method (and it's shortcuts) works in such way that it handles all events directly inside jQuery bubbling and calling the callbacks registered using `on()` (or any of the shorthands).

The main issue in jQuery is that it only resend the "click" event to the DOM because it tries to use a method in the DOM element with the same name as the event. In the DOM, (at the moment) the only situation when that happens is the "click" event. That's why I was getting the click event and not the rest of the events.

With that, the mistery and confusion was, finally, solved. uff!